# Unable to clear footer from Google Document

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

When I run the code below, I receive a TypeError:

> TypeError: Cannot call method "clear" of null. (line 3, file "Code")

from the line: `footer.clear()`

```
function insertFooterDate() {
  var footer = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getFooter();
  footer.clear();  // Line 3 - gets the footer & clears all data in footer. 

  //Get date
  var date = new Date();
  var month = date.getMonth()+1;
  var day = date.getDate();
  var year = date.getFullYear();
  var hour = date.getHours()+1;
  var minute = date.getMinutes()+1;
  var filename = doc.getName();

  footer.appendParagraph(day + '/' + month + '/' + year + ' ' + filename);  
  //adds date to footer with filename
}
```

Why do I get this error when my code executes?

Comment: There is no footer in your active document.

Comment: You can add a test to check `footer` for being truthy.  `if (footer) {footer.clear();}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no footer in a Google Docs file, you cannot call methods on that which does not exist. The Apps Script Document Service provides a method to [add a footer](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document#addFooter()), so you should make the decision to either abort your methods that require a footer if there is not one already, or create one. The decision will depend on what your methods are supposed to do.

```
function doStuffWithFooter_(myGDoc) {
  if (!myGDoc) return;
  const footer = myGDoc.getFooter();
  if (!footer) {
    console.warn("Document '" + myGDoc.getId() + "' had no footer.");
    return;
  }
  ... // code that should only run if the doc already had a footer
}

function addDateToFooter_(myGDoc) {
  if (!myGDoc) return;
  var footer = myGDoc.getFooter();
  if (!footer) {
    // no footer, so create one.
    footer = myGDoc.addFooter();
    console.log("Created footer for document '" + myGDoc.getId() + "'.");
  }
  ... // do stuff with footer, because we made sure one exists.
}
```